# sql query to get duplicate records with different dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, cakephp, datediff

I need to get records with different date field ,

table **Sites:**

```
field id
reference
created
```

Every day we add lot of records, so I need to do a function that extract all records existing with duplicates of rows just was added, to do some notifications.

the conditions that i can't get is the difference between records of the current day and the old data in the table should be (one day to 4 days) .

If is there any simple query to do that without using transaction .

Comment: how about a `select fieldId,reference,count(*) as theCount from Sites group by fieldId,reference having theCount>1` ... or `select field id,reference,count(*) as theCount from Sites group by field id,reference having theCount>1` ... where in the 2nd one `field id` has backticks around it

Comment: or better yet, don't allow duplicates to begin with, unless the days are long and there is nothing to do but clean data

Comment: I think your question could have been written more clearly. The comments to date don't seem to notice that these aren't strict duplicates but rows within 4 days of each other. Also, your title implies you want a query but in the question you say you want a function. You have not stated what the PK for the table is, or at least that `fieldid` and `reference` distinguish a key to each set to check for duplicate (within 4 days) `created` values. So, you should have been clearer in what you want, and provided an example of what you have tried so far.  Sample data in and out would also help.

Comment: comments are the fun area, where one is not so foolish as to plop them in an Answer, @Turophile. Whether duplicates are 2 days old or 92, what is the difference. The OP can figure it out

Comment: @Drew, my point was that this isn't a typical "I don't have a unique key" duplicates problem, but a "I need to match some rows in the table against other rows with a difference in dates as the crucial difference" and that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: @Turophile, gotcha, I think. But the comment "The comments to date don't seem to notice that these aren't strict duplicates" ... and that I had the only comments, and I had the group by that I did, wouldn't suggest what you wrote. Rather, it would suggest that I noticed they aren't strict duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand what you mean by duplicate records, but here's a basic date query:

```
SELECT fieldId, reference, created, DATE(created) as the_date 
FROM Sites
WHERE the_date 
BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 3 DAY ) )
AND DATE ( NOW() )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm making several assumptions such as:

- You don't want the "first" row returned
- Duplicates don't carry the
  date forward (The next after initial 4 days is not a duplicate)
- The 4 days means +4 days so Day 5 is included

So, my code is :

```
 with originals as (
  select s1.*
  from sites as s1
  where 0 = (
    select count(*) 
    from sites as s2 
    where s1.field_id = s2.field_id
    and s1.reference = s2.reference
    and s1.created <> s2.created
    and DATEDIFF(DAY,s2.created, s1.created) between 1 and 4
    )
  )
select s1.* 
from sites as s1
inner join originals as o
on s1.field_id = o.field_id
and s1.reference = o.reference
and s1.created <> o.created
where DATEDIFF(DAY,o.created, s1.created) between 1 and 4
order by 1,2,3;
```

Here it is in a fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b407/20

This could be simpler if some conditions are relaxed.

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot for every one who tried to help me ,

i have found this solution after lot of test

```
SELECT `id`,`reference`,count(`config_id`) as c,`created` FROM `sites` 
where datediff(date(current_date()),date(`created`)) < 4    
group by `reference`
having c > 1
```

thanks a lot for your help